# "НЕ" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, частица-не

***Они не/обходимы, но не/достаточны.***
Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

В каком случае? "Необходимы" - точно слитно, слово "обходимый" если и существует, то антонимичного значения к "необходимый" не несет.
А вот второй случй - интереснее. В обычном контексте, да в сочетании с "необходимы",  слитное написание более вероятно.

Но в принципе может быть и раздельное написание, особенно в значении "не является достаточным". 
Так, в математике "достаточность" и "необходимость" - вполне формализованые понятия в отличие от "недостаточности". Поэтому во фразах типа *"Делимость на два является необходимым, но не достаточным условием делимости на шесть"* однозначно требуется раздельное написание.

Можете контекст привести?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что слитно.

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется что точно слитно

Answer (score 0):

"Они необходимы, но недостаточны". По-моему, оба слова пишутся здесь только слитно. И первое краткое прилагательное, и второе тоже без НЕ в данном контексте не употребляются.